# When the menu is collapsed, how do I align the menu items to the left with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a rather basic menu system using Bootstrap 3, and that's actually what I was going for. However, when the menu is collapsed, I've noticed that all the items are centered - that throws off my design sense for what I'm trying to do.

Instead of centered collapse items, I'd like to push them to the left instead, but I am not sure how to do so. This is my existing HTML, using default Bootstrap 3 settings for the most part.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="NavBox">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Now</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Then</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sign In</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navbar-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchBar">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Is there a pre-existing class to push the collapsed items ONLY left?

Comment: With your code I edited the source, the items are already aligned to the left on collapsed mode. Maybe you are missing some custom CSS?

Comment: Argh! That was it, and I feel stupid. Yeah, a text-align in my header is overriding Bootstrap 3. I'll fix that.

Comment: Much better. Changed the scope to not include the entire header, and that fixed.

Comment: That's good. Should I close the question since the problem is no longer reproducible with your current code?

Comment: Sure, thank you again.